# Adding blog to an existing website with the same domain name

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a working website in Yii frame work with domainename.fr
Now i want to add a wordpress blog to be accessible in : domainename.fr/wp
I have tried to add a rewrite rule in the .htaccess file but it overrided by another rule that redirect every unknown path to the root (domainename.fr).

How can i do that with just alias, i mean to point /wp to /path_of_my_blog

my .conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domainename.fr

    DocumentRoot /var/www/path/htdocs/src/web
    <Directory /var/www/path/htdocs/src/web>
        Options +Indexes
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

my blog path is /var/www/path/htdocs/wp

Comment: `Alias /wp /var/www/path/htdocs/wp` doesn't work?

Comment: Unfortunately nope, always **/wp** leads to **/**